# set cornerRadius and setbackgroundimage to UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, cornerradius, setbackground

I am trying to set cornerRadius of UIButton but I dont know how to do it.

If I do like this:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

works well, if I do like this :

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:radialGradient]];
```

the corners are not rounded.

I know I could solve this whit

```
 [button.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

but I specifically looking for different solution, because I add some arrows to the button and if I set mask to bounds the arrow are masked.

EDIT :

radialGradient is made whit func

```
+ (UIImage *)getRadialGradientImage:(CGSize)size centre:(CGPoint)centre radius:(float)radius startColor:(UIColor *)startColor endColor:(UIColor *)endColor{

// Initialise
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 1);

// Create the gradient's colours
size_t num_locations = 2;
CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

const CGFloat *component_first = CGColorGetComponents([startColor CGColor]);

CGFloat red1 = component_first[0];
CGFloat green1 = component_first[1];
CGFloat blue1 = component_first[2];

const CGFloat *component_second = CGColorGetComponents([endColor CGColor]);
CGFloat red2 = component_second[0];
CGFloat green2 = component_second[1];
CGFloat blue2 = component_second[2];

const CGFloat components[8] = { red1,green1,blue1,1,red2,green2,blue2,1}; // End color

CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

// Normalise the 0-1 ranged inputs to the width of the image
CGPoint myCentrePoint = CGPointMake(centre.x * size.width, centre.y * size.height);
float myRadius = MIN(size.width, size.height) * radius;

// Draw it!
CGContextDrawRadialGradient (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), myGradient, myCentrePoint,
                             0, myCentrePoint, myRadius,
                             kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

// Grab it as an autoreleased image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// Clean up
CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorspace); // Necessary?
CGGradientRelease(myGradient); // Necessary?
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); // Clean up
return image;
}
```

Comment: Can U show the **radialGradient** declaration >.?

Answer (score 49):

Here is how I would create a button through code and set its background color.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100,50);
[btn setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0f green:0.0/255.0f  blue:0.0/255.0f alpha:0.7]];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 50.0);//width and height should be same  value
btn.clipsToBounds = YES;

btn.layer.cornerRadius = 20;//half of the width
btn.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
btn.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Below is the image of the button that is related with the above code
[image]

You can always play around with code and create the colors that you need for background and border. Hope this would help you out.

Answer (score 23):

```
btn.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

i Just added this and it worked for me. I was actually able to set corner radius to UIButton with setting an image to that particular UIButton.

Comment: That is awesome! Now I know that bounds include border radius.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the image in your button background then you need to set `clipsTobounds` to true.

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10 
button.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also have:

```
btn.clipsToBounds = true;
```

Comment: Be careful, `YES`/`NO` should be used with Objective-C while `true`/`false` may be used for Swift.

Comment: @JAL You can also use `true`/`TRUE` and `false`/`FALSE` in Objective-C, along with `YES` and `NO`.

Comment: It's better to use YES/NO with the Objective-C BOOL type, since true/false map to the C bool type.

Answer (score 2):

//create button like this

```
     UIButton *cancel=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 9,35,35)];
    cancel.backgroundColor=[UIColor  colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackX.png"]];
[cancel setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cancel.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [cancel.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    cancel.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    cancel.clipsToBounds=YES;
    cancel.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
    [cancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelbtnclk1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:cancel];
```

Before that add QuartzCore Framework and import  QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h in your .h file.

hope it will helps you..

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but I specifically dont want clipToBounds.

Comment: Yes, but then it is not cornered :D

Answer (score 1):

Using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, you can use the `cgContext` property of `UIGraphicsImageRendererContext` to access the `CGContext` and add a rounded path:

```
UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { context in
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    let clipPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
    context.cgContext.addPath(clipPath)
    context.cgContext.setFillColor(self.cgColor)
    context.cgContext.fillPath()
}
```

Added as an extension to `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {
    public func image(_ size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10), cornerRadius: CGFloat = 4) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { context in
            let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
            let clipPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
            context.cgContext.addPath(clipPath)
            context.cgContext.setFillColor(self.cgColor)
            context.cgContext.fillPath()
        }
    }
}
```

This approach will also allow you to add a shadow to the button unlike using `clipsToBounds`.

Answer (score -1):

Set corner Radius in Identity Inspector for Button. See Pic

[image]

Set Background image in Attribute Inspector for Button. See pic

[image]